# Оптимизация для Retina

Tags: html, вёрстка, оптимизация

Здравствуйте. Встал такой вопрос как оптимизация изображения/текста, для retina дисплеев. Как этого можно добиться? И как оценить полученный результат, на обычном не retina мониторе?

Comment: Добавь нужные теги. Неясно к чему относится вопрос. Этот вопрос можно класифицировать как к верстке хтмл-а, так и к написанию GUI на свифте, так и к написанию гуя на основе ксамл. Переформулируй вопрос, короче.

Comment: Добавил метки, думаю так будет яснее, что требуется.

Comment: svg, иконочные шрифты, srcset. В Chrome, Firefox - увеличением масштаба 200% и 300%